# How get request with axios body raw json in vue js

Tags: javascript, axios

send request with postman get answare request like this

[image: screenShot post man]

send request with axios in vue js like this:

```js
axios.get("http://url/api/package/questions?language=Persian", {
      headers: {
        'content-type': ' application/json'
      },
      data: {
        "package-slug": "six-dims",
      }}
    )
    .then(res => {
      console.log("my call", res)
    });
```

get resposne server error 500

Comment: You have a leading space before your `content-type` value. Simply remove the `headers` since that is the default for Axios anyway. Also, GET requests cannot have `data`

Comment: It does not work without data
but in postman have data and request success

Comment: If you want to send `data`, you must use either a POST or PUT request. It will be ignored for a GET request

Comment: are you have any solution without use axios ?

Comment: I've already told you. Remove the `headers` and `data`, ie `axios.get("http://url/api/package/questions?language=Persian").then(res => console.log('my call', res))`. If you still get a 500 response, check your server's error log

Answer (score 5):

You should not use a GET request to send JSON data in body. I suppose you should use either POST, PUT or PATCH to make this HTTP request. I suppose `axios` doesn't allow you to add data in the post body. You can try this, after changing your method type to POST on your server. But still you can find it out more deeper reading their docs.
I have edited the code, you can find out your syntax issue also.

```
axios.post('http://url/api/package/questions?language=Persian', {'package-slug': 'six-dims'}, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
 .then(function(result) { 
  console.log(result);
 });
```

Comment: Why add the `Content-type` header? `application/json` is the default for all Axios POST, PUT and PATCH requests

Comment: @Phil no data is the request body, config is a different parameter that is used to configure the data to be sent.
And yeah it is default, but I just added it because he mentioned it in the question.